storerestresource annotation doesn't create REST Endpoints
I'm trying to use Spring Content REST library from paulcwarren, the issue I have faced is that when I create the storage interface it doesn't create the rest api endpoints, because when I try to call for ex. localhost:8080/storage/{some_id} it returns 404 Not Found, so for me this indicates that the REST API is not properly created.
Does anyone know what may be the problem ?
p.s. I don't have any rest controllers registered, I have one more Data Rest Jpa Repository which works fine with @RepositoryRestResource
@StoreRestResource(linkRel = "storage", path = "storage")
@Repository
public interface StoreContentSource extends ContentStore<ContentSource, UUID> {
}


My apologies, it was my mistake, instead of sending like ordinary ID that is primary key from db I was thinking I need to send UUID and that's why I was getting Not found, because before calling setContent() there is a call to repo findById() which requires Long not UUID.
Now I see it works.
